# Different html code for different HITs in mechanical turk

Tags: html, mechanicalturk

I have multiple HITs in mechanical turk, each contains a different assignment. This is part of an experiment, and I want the participants to be randomly divided between he different states (i.e. different HITs). I understand that I can use the           ${} feature and provide different texts in a .csv, but I want the differences to be more than just the text... I would prefer to use a different code for each option (state). Is there a convenient way to do it through the html code? I'm kind of new to html code...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good way to do this via the web interface. However, it could be done using Python and the MTurk API, as detailed in this tutorial, [*Tutorial: A beginner’s guide to crowdsourcing ML training data with Python and MTurk*](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-a-beginners-guide-to-crowdsourcing-ml-training-data-with-python-and-mturk-d8df4bdf2977)

In the portion of the code where you assign the question xml/HTML to `question`:

```
question = open(name='questions.xml',mode='r').read()
```

you could dynamically pick your different, pre-generated `question.xml` templates